# Index selection behaviour in oracle in case of multiple indexes on same columns

Tags: oracle

I am not getting the index selection behavior in oracle in case a column is common between two indexes.

Below is the sample code:

```
create table emp 
(id number,
dpt number);
```

and i have 2 indexes on this table:

```
create unique index ind1 on emp (id);
create unique index ind2 on emp (id,dpt);
```

this is the data i have used:

```
Insert into EMP (ID,DPT) values (1,2);
Insert into EMP (ID,DPT) values (2,2);
Insert into EMP (ID,DPT) values (3,2);
```

when i am fetching data based on some filter condition like,

```
select * from emp where id =2;
```

IND2 is getting used as per explain plan

and when i am using range query IND1 used:

```
select * from emp where id > 2;
```

I am not getting any specific reason about such index behavior.

Is there any specific logic being used here to decide which index to be used in each of these queries.

Comment: @Jon Heller...thanks for your comments.Updated with the data i used.But now,strangely,both the queries are using index IND2 only whereas earlier there was a difference in behavior.

Comment: It's quite strange, that this is even possible. In older Oracle versions there was a limitation that column set on one index must not be a "prefix" of other index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single lookup, an `INDEX RANGE SCAN` on a composite index is cheaper than 
both `INDEX UNIQUE SCAN` and `TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID` required for a single-column index.  The composite index may be larger and have more branches, but each leaf contains all values needed for the results.  Accessing that extra branch is cheaper than accessing a whole different data structure (the table segment).

Here is a slightly larger sample schema.  The DDL in the question is useful, but to truly understand these problems it's important to add sample data and show how statistics are gathered.

```
create table emp(id number,dpt number);
create unique index ind1 on emp (id);
create unique index ind2 on emp (id,dpt);
insert into emp select level,level from dual connect by level <= 100000;
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'emp');
end;
/
```

As in the question, the default plan uses IND2.

```
explain plan for select * from emp where id=2;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 1519675770

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |      |     1 |    10 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  INDEX RANGE SCAN| IND2 |     1 |    10 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("ID"=2)
```

A hint shows what the IND1 plan would look like.  Note that now the plan has to access both the index and the table.

```
explain plan for select /*+ index(emp ind1) */ * from emp where id =2;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 2624671090

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |      |     1 |    10 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| EMP  |     1 |    10 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | IND1 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("ID"=2)
```

This only answers the first question.  I don't have a good explanation for the second question.  If you could modify the sample data to re-create that scenario we could investigate it.